# Adding caption or title to a TIKZ plot in .TEX documentclass{standalone}

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have exported a plot generated from VSCode as a `.tex` file. Now I want to add a title or caption to the top of the plot. I'm not sure how to do that! any suggestions are welcome! Thanks. The code looks like the below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

     
{LONG Plotting CODE}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put the tikzpicture inside a figure environment, you can use \caption{...}.  If you put it inside a minipage, you can use \captionof{figure}{...}.  (caption or capt-of packages.)

Comment: thanks for responding.  I tried to add the /caption inside the figure environment but it messed up the entire canvas width and height. some plots are going outside of the visible window.

Comment: We will need a Minimal Working Example (MWE) to solve case speciffic problems.  You can replace a large tikzpicture with `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` (if you know the width and height).

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors of the `current bounding box` node: try anchors `.north`, `.west`, `.north east`, `.120`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,nodes={black}]
(0,0)  coordinate (A) node[below left] {$A$}--
(5,0)   coordinate (B) node[below right]{$B$}--
(1,3.5) coordinate (C) node[above]      {$C$}--cycle;

\path (current bounding box.south) node[below]{This is a triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In case of several sub-blocks, then the `local bounding box` may help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L,shift={(-6,0)}]
\draw[blue,fill=blue!20]
(0,0)--(5,0)--(1.2,3.8)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=C]
\draw[magenta,fill=magenta!30]
(0,0) node[shift={(30:.8)}]{$60^{\circ}$}--
(4,0) node[shift={(150:.8)}]{$60^{\circ}$}--
([turn]120:4)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,shift={(6,0)}]
\draw[cyan,fill=cyan!20]
(0,0)--(4,0)--(0,3)--cycle;
\draw[cyan] (0,0) rectangle +(.5,.5);
\end{scope}

\path (L.south) node[below=5mm]{A triangle};
\path (C.south) node[below=5mm]{An equilateral triangle};
\path (R.south) node[below=5mm]{A right triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```